# Modal image is not closing (react) - JavaScript Event Not Working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, modal-dialog

Trying to write a function to close a modal image. Function is not executing at all, so that, there is no result. Using react lifecycles to add and remove event listeners on event. Any ideas what kind of issue is happening right here? Have attached the code, please check where I did a mistake.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ImageGalleryItem from "../ImageGalleryItem/ImageGalleryItem";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Modal from "../Modal/Modal";

export default class ImageGallery extends Component {
  state = {
    open: false,
    largeImageURL: "",
  };

  setLargeImg = (e) => {
    this.setState({ largeImageURL: e });
  };

  render() {
    let imageListContent;
    const { images } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <ul className="ImageGallery">
          {images
            ? (imageListContent = images.map((image) => (
                <ImageGalleryItem
                  image={image.webformatURL}
                  title={image.title}
                  largePic={image.largeImageURL}
                  setLargeImg={this.setLargeImg}
                  key={image.id}
                />
              )))
            : (imageListContent = null)}
        </ul>
        {this.state.largeImageURL && (
          <Modal
            largeImageURL={this.state.largeImageURL}
            state={this.state}
            setLargeImg={this.setLargeImg}
          />
        )}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Modal component

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Modal extends Component {
  escFunction = (event) => {
    if (event.target.code === "Escape") {
      this.props.setLargeImg(null);
    }
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener("keyDown", this.escFunction);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("keyDown", this.escFunction);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Overlay">
        <div className="Modal">
          <img src={this.props.largeImageURL} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You cant change the props; the parent sets those and are then immutable. Use a state to   open/close the modal instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Function is not executing at all, so that, there is no result.

DOM events are key sensitive. `keyDown` event does not exist. However, `keydown` does. Simply switch from small `d` to big `D`

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  window.removeEventListener("keydown", this.escFunction);
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Lastly, `event.target.code` will return undefined. This property does not exist. Simply check for `event.key`

```
escFunction = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Escape") {
        this.props.setLargeImg(null);
    }
};
```

Comment: thx, but it looks like this is not the only problem